# Place variable in require function

Tags: php

I'm trying to require a php view dynamically. So that it print a pdf using phpwkhtmltopdf.

First I send the name of the viewer page from my handler page by using a button:

```
<form action="print.php" method="get">
 <button name="printit" type="submit" value="m_dpgmi1.php">print</button>
</form>
```

Then I catch it in the page where I've the phpwkhtmltopdf function:

```
<?php
require '../vendor/autoload.php';

$template = $_GET['printit'];    

use mikehaertl\wkhtmlto\Pdf;

ob_start();

require "'$template'";
$content = ob_get_clean();

// You can pass a filename, a HTML string, an URL or an options array to the constructor
$pdf = new Pdf($content);

$pdf -> setOptions(['orientation' => 'Landscape']);
$pdf->binary = 'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe';
$pdf->send();
?>
```

Unfortunately I get an error:
    `Warning: require('m_dpgmi1.php'): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

It looks right `require('m_dpgmi1.php')`, except for the braces. Is there a way to place a variable value as an require argument?

Comment: HI,
be careful there is a highly security bridge here. Does not call directly a page from an external data. After, you user `require "'$template'"`. Why using `"` + `'` ? Use `require "$template";` or `require $template;`. Here the script try to load a file with quote included on the name

Comment: Another point: use something like this: 1. On your form `<button ... value="m_dpgmi1" />` ; 2. and on your code `switch($template) { case 'm_dpgmi1' : require 'm_dpgmi1.php'; break; default: exit('Error: template does not exists'); break; }` :)

Comment: Thank you Georges! It is solved, and I'll use the switch case statement.